# How to find the highest value in a year and in all months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return a year in which was the most contracts made and a month throughout all years - in which month the highest number of contracts is made.

I've tried:

```
SELECT
     cal.CalendarYear
    ,cal.MonthOfYear
    ,COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM dim.Application app
    JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON app.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateId
--WHERE (CalendarYear IS NULL) OR (MonthOfYear IS NULL)
GROUP BY
     cal.CalendarYear
    ,cal.MonthOfYear
WITH CUBE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

and...

```
--;WITH maxYear AS (
    SELECT TOP 1
        cal.CalendarYear AS [Year]
        ,0               AS [Month]
        ,COUNT(*) AS Cnt
    FROM dim.Application app
        JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON app.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateId
    GROUP BY cal.CalendarYear
--  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
--)
UNION ALL
--,maxMonth AS (
    SELECT TOP 1
         0                      AS [Year]
        ,cal.MonthOfYear        AS [Month]
        ,COUNT(*)               AS Cnt
    FROM dim.Application app
        JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON app.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateID
    GROUP BY cal.MonthOfYear
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
--)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't the second solution work?

Comment: Because it's not ordered by highest values.

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: What I don't want: 2014-08 7354
What I want: 2016 86221, 11 6854

Comment: Oh I see you want novembers from all years. I will update my answer.

Comment: Not so exactly. I want to return a year with the highest number of contracts and a month no matter of a year.

Answer (score 1):

This will `ORDER BY` each portion of the UNION independently, and still have the results `joined` in one SELECT...

```
SELECT x.* FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1
        cal.CalendarYear AS [Year]
        ,0               AS [Month]
        ,COUNT(*) AS Cnt
    FROM dim.Application app
        JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON app.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateId
    GROUP BY cal.CalendarYear
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) x

UNION ALL

SELECT x.* FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1
         0                      AS [Year]
        ,cal.MonthOfYear        AS [Month]
        ,COUNT(*)               AS Cnt
    FROM dim.Application app
        JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON app.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateID
    GROUP BY cal.MonthOfYear
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the counts per year and month and use `row_number` to get the year and month with the highest contracts.

```
SELECT 
MAX(CASE WHEN year_rank=1 then Year END) as Highest_contracts_year,
MAX(CASE WHEN year_rank=1 then Year_count END) as Year_Contracts_count
MAX(CASE WHEN month_year_rank=1 then Month END) as Highest_contracts_Month,
MAX(CASE WHEN month_year_rank=1 then Month_Year_count END) as MonthYear_Contracts_count    
FROM (SELECT T.*
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Year_Cnt DESC) as Year_rank
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Month_Year_Cnt DESC) as Month_Year_rank
      FROM (SELECT 
            cal.CalendarYear AS [Year]
            ,cal.MonthOfYear AS [Month]
            ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY cal.CalendarYear) AS Year_Cnt
            ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY cal.MonthOfYear) AS Month_Year_Cnt
            FROM dim.Application app
            JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON app.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateId
           ) T
      ) T
```

You should specify what needs to be done when there are ties for highest counts. Assuming you need all highest count rows when there are ties, use

```
With ranks as 
         (SELECT T.*
          ,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Year_Cnt DESC) as Year_rank
          ,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Month_Year_Cnt DESC) as Month_Year_rank
          FROM (SELECT 
                cal.CalendarYear AS [Year]
                ,cal.MonthOfYear AS [Month]
                ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY cal.CalendarYear) AS Year_Cnt
                ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY cal.MonthOfYear) AS Month_Year_Cnt
                FROM dim.Application app
                JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON app.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateId
               ) T
          ) 
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Year,Year_Cnt FROM RANKS WHERE Year_rank=1) ry
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Month,Month_Year_Cnt FROM RANKS WHERE Month_Year_rank=1) rm
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This might be what you want, unless you want it on single line:

```
select calendaryear AS 'year/month', cnt from (
SELECT TOP 1
     cal.CalendarYear
    ,COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM dim.Application AS app
    JOIN dim.Calendar AS cal ON app.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateId
GROUP BY
     cal.CalendarYear
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) as year
UNION ALL
select MonthOfYear, Cnt FROM ( 
SELECT TOP 1
     cal.CalendarYear
    ,cal.MonthOfYear
    ,COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM dim.Application AS app
    JOIN dim.Calendar AS cal ON app.ApplicationDateID = cal.DateId
GROUP BY
     cal.CalendarYear
    ,cal.MonthOfYear
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) AS month
```

It returns following result where month 3 is in fact 2016:

```
year/month  cnt
2017        4
3           2
```

I have used following data as input

```
create table #calendar (DateId int, calendaryear int, monthofyear int)
create table #application (applicationdateId int)

insert into #calendar values (1,2017,01)
insert into #calendar values (2,2017,02)
insert into #calendar values (3,2017,03)
insert into #calendar values (4,2016,01)
insert into #calendar values (5,2016,03)

insert into #application values (1)
insert into #application values (1)
insert into #application values (2)
insert into #application values (3)
insert into #application values (4)
insert into #application values (5)
insert into #application values (5)
```

Comment: Yes, but I need it within one query.
What I don't want: 2014-08 7354 What I want: 2016 86221, 11 6854.

Comment: @StanislavJirák See updated query. It should give you what you want. If I understand it correctly.